# Can one show this is equivalent to erf(x) by elementary means?

Tags: integration, error-function

According to the PDF at [this](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf) link (eqn 12), the following is true:
$$\text{erf}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-t} \sin(2x\sqrt{t})\frac{dt}{t} $$

I would like to use this identity as part of a presentation to my students (the integral can be derived in an intuitive way for a heat diffusion problem). If need be I can simply assert "and this is known to be equivalent to the error function" but I'd rather prove it for them. However since the group are not mathematicians I would need to be able to show it using elementary methods; for example integration by parts is fine, but contour integration is not.

I have tried and failed to show the equivalence. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

By the substitution $\sqrt{t}\rightarrow \pi u$, we get
\begin{align}
2\frac{1}{\pi}\int^\infty_0 e^{-\pi^2u^2}\frac{\sin(2\pi x u)}{u}\ du = \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-\pi^2u^2}\frac{\sin(2\pi x u)}{\pi u}\ du. 
\end{align}

Apply Plancherel's theorem, which states
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(x)\overline{g(x)}\ dx = \int^\infty_{-\infty} \hat f(\xi)\overline{\hat g(\xi)}\ d\xi,
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-\pi^2u^2}\frac{\sin(2\pi x u)}{\pi u}\ du=&\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-t^2}\chi_{[-x, x]}(t)\ dt 
= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int^x_0 e^{-t^2}\ dt =\operatorname{erf}(x).
\end{align}

I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to check

> \begin{align} \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-\pi^2 x^2}e^{-2\pi i x\xi}\ dx
>  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\xi^2}. \end{align}

**Hint:** Complete the square. Formally ignored the complex number in the square and perform a $u$-substitution.

Comment: Not exactly elementary, but straightforward.

Comment: @martycohen You are correct. The moment I did the $u$-sub and saw $\operatorname{sinc}$ function, I realize there had to be Plancherel. Besides, the attached paper is definitely assuming nontrivial math knowledge.

Comment: Thanks. They haven't met Plancherel's but they have met Parseval's theorem, so they would see it as analogous. Once that is accepted, the derivation is clear.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\tag{1a}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \frac{\sin(2x\sqrt{t})}{t} dt
&= x \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \mathrm{e}^{i2x\theta \sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} dt d\theta \\
\tag{1b}
&= 2x \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-y^{2}+i2x\theta y} dy d\theta \\
\tag{1c}
&= 2x \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2} \theta ^{2}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(y-ix\theta)^{2}} dy d\theta \\
\end{align}

Notes:

a. Use $$\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\phi} = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{i\phi w} dw$$

b. $\sqrt{t} = y$

c. Complete the square.

Evaluate
\begin{align}
\int \mathrm{e}^{-(y-ix\theta)^{2}} dy &= \int \mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}} dz \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \mathrm{erf}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \mathrm{erf}(y-ix\theta)
\end{align}
here we let $z = y-ix\theta $. Applying limits to the integral yields
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(y-ix\theta)^{2}} dy 
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \mathrm{erf}(y-ix\theta) \Big|_{0}^{\infty} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} [1 + i \mathrm{erfi}(x\theta)]
\tag{2}
\end{align}

Substituting equation 2 into equation 1c yields two integrals. Dropping constants we have first
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2} \theta ^{2}} d\theta &= \frac{1}{x} \int \mathrm{e}^{-w^{2}} dw \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2x} \mathrm{erf}(w) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2x} \mathrm{erf}(x\theta) \Big|_{-1}^{1} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x} \mathrm{erf}(x)
\tag{3}
\end{align}
secondly, we have
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2} \theta ^{2}} \mathrm{erfi}(x\theta) d\theta = 0
\end{equation}
noting that the imaginary error function is an odd function.

Putting the pieces together yields
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \frac{\sin(2x\sqrt{t})}{t} dt
&= 2x \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2} \theta ^{2}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(y-ix\theta)^{2}} dy d\theta \\
&= 2x \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x} \mathrm{erf}(x) \\
&= \pi \mathrm{erf}(x)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I believe they would follow every step of that, although they haven't met the imaginary error function so that would need to be introduced.

Comment: I do hope that it is useful. I could not think of a simpler method. However, it is the weekend, so there may be a clever, simple solution yet to come.